# node.js nested async.eachSeries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback, nested, async.js

I'm just new into node and for ending new into async.js. I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is doable (guess it is) or if my approach to do it is the right on (guess its not). Here is the thing:

this code is to manage some instagram data, so I will explain everything based on what the code actually needs to do to be more understandable.

1. connect to mongoDB, get some Instagram accounts id's (done)
2. for each id I want to get the las 10 posts (I already have that saved in my database).
3. for that 10 items of each account, I need to get the sum of (comments + likes) and thake that value to the out code of the first eachSeries call.

   ```
   router.get('/users_all', function(req, res) {   

       User.find().sort({'counts.followed_by': 'descending'}).exec(function(err, users) { 

           async.eachSeries(users, function(item, outerCallback) { 

               Media.find({'userId': item.user_id}).exec(function(err, medias) {       

                   var count = 0;

                   async.eachSeries(medias, function(item, outerCallback2) {               

                       count += item.comments_count + item.likes_count;            
                   });     

               });

               item.totalAmount = count;

           }); 

           res.json(users);

       });

   }
   ```

I have just not set the callback calls out of each eachSeries beacuse I dont know where to put them, and I think my code is more simple to understand this way.

If need more clarification about the code pleas ask.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're mostly there (at least with the callbacks).

If you check out the docs on async at https://github.com/caolan/async you'll see that the call for `eachSeries` also has a callback, so once the series is complete you can perform some action.

It's looking like your code is trying to complete once the inner series is done adding all of the values to count. so you async.eachSeries calls will end up looking like this (plus some additional error handling which I'd definitely recommend for your mongo queries).

```
router.get('/users_all', function(req, res) {
    User.find().sort({'counts.followed_by': 'descending'}).exec(function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({code: 500, message: 'Internal server error'});
        } else {
            async.eachSeries(users, function (item, outerCallback) {
                Media.find({'userId': item.user_id}).exec(function (err, medias) {
                    if (err) {
                        outerCallback(err);
                    } else {
                        var count = 0;
                        async.eachSeries(medias, function (item, innerCallback) {
                            count += item.comments_count + item.likes_count;
                            innerCallback();
                        }, function () {
                            if (err) {
                                outerCallback(err);
                            } else {
                                item.totalAmount = count;
                                outerCallback();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }, function () {
                res.json(users);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is it doesn't look like you're actually limiting yourself to just the 10 most recent items, unless that's all you have saved in your database.

Comment: You are right, I simplyfied the code to dont lilmit to 10 the results from media model, but i just replaced the Media.find in my code. It works perfect, thanks for your help. Have to ask to learn something from this: You basicaly use the callbacks to "somehow" end each iteration of the eachSeries loop and get the result at the function you add to the eachSeries method ? is that simple ? Thanks

Comment: Not super experienced and might say things a bit wrong but my understanding is basically instead of a return to end the function saying you're done with your processing, you let the eachSeries function know that iteration is complete through that callback. Then once they're all done, you define your own callback that'll get called once each callback in the array is completed. So yup! That simple! You can also include error bodies in your callbacks and async handles those a little differently.